# Magento Get Different options to select from Options.php

Tags: php, magento

I have a admin back-end options section/module to control few things like upload slider images, site background, banners etc.
That is simple cause it just requires xml code in system.xml.
I want to add different drop-downs, radio buttons, multiple select. 
I have the following code in Options.php
Its giving me options to select one, two or three for every drop-down, radio or multi select.
What I have to define here to get different options? not just one, two and Three.

```
<?php
    class Options_CustomConfig_Model_Options
    {
      /**
       * Provide available options as a value/label array
       *
       * @return array
       */
      public function toOptionArray()
      {
        return array(
          array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'One'),
          array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
          array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three')                   
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: what i mean is to have more options not just one two three in all. For example if i want 3 different drop-downs lets say one has options like 10, 100, 1000. Another drop-down with different options like A, B, C. And another like Him, Her, Them. Understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can create individual models for individual drop down and specify relevant model in the system.xml while creating field.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Form what I understand in config.xml in models I should define another class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Different Source model if options are different in configuration field.

here is the some useful links for creating source model:

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/source-model

http://www.atwix.com/magento/frontend-backend-source/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what needs to be done to get more options: I created another folder in Model called Optiontwo and inside Option.php. Class for options.php have to have folded in it like this: class CustomConfig_Model_Optiontwo_Options. And then in system.xml for source_model have to be declared like this: customconfig/Optiontwo_options

Thanks to [Adrsh Khatri](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9860/adarsh-khatri) for pointing in the right direction.